# linq to xml query: Object reference not set error while trying to retrieve child element

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

i am trying to retrieve all the child elements but getting System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal. Object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

my c# code retrieve all the question on according to the test_id and category_id passed:-

```
public static List<Questions> GetQuestion_Catgy(int test_id, int ctgy_id)
        {
            try
            {
                XDocument data = XDocument.Load(docurl);
                return (from exm in data.Descendants("test_details")
                        where exm.Attribute("id").Value.Equals(test_id.ToString())
                        from ctgy in exm.Descendants("category")
                        where ctgy.Attribute("id").Value.Equals(ctgy_id.ToString())
                        orderby (int)ctgy.Attribute("id")
                        select new Questions
                        {
                            quesID = Convert.ToInt32(ctgy.Attribute("id").Value),
                            quesSTRING = ctgy.Attribute("ques").Value,
                            quesRATE = Convert.ToInt32(ctgy.Attribute("rating").Value),
                            quesOPT1 = (string)ctgy.Element("opt1").Value,
                            quesOPT2 = (string)ctgy.Element("opt2").Value,
                            quesOPT3 = (string)ctgy.Element("opt3").Value,
                            quesOPT4 = (string)ctgy.Element("opt4").Value,
                            quesANS = Convert.ToInt32(ctgy.Element("ans").Value),
                            quesIMG = (string)ctgy.Element("img").Value
                        }).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(ex.Data + "\n" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

my xml

```
<test_details id="1" name="test exam" time="30" marks="100" difficulty="1">
    <category id="1" name="HTML">
      <question id="1" ques="what is HTML ?" rating="5">
        <opt1>Markup Language</opt1>
        <opt2>Scripting Language</opt2>
        <opt3>Server-Side Lanugae</opt3>
        <opt4>Client-Side Language</opt4>
        <ans>1</ans>
        <img>null</img>
      </question>
      <question id="2" ques="what is LMTH ?" rating="5">
        <opt1>Markup Language</opt1>
        <opt2>Scripting Language</opt2>
        <opt3>Server-Side Lanugae</opt3>
        <opt4>Client-Side Language</opt4>
        <ans>2</ans>
        <img>null</img>
      </question>
    </category>
    <category id="2" name="C#" />
  </test_details>
```

[image]

Comment: By rethrowing the wrapped exception, you'll lose the original stack trace. If you aren't handling the exception, let it propogate on the own. (The original stack trace may also be useful in finding your null ref.)

Comment: the query retrieving  question element but the problem is in selection & assigning part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to go down an extra level to the 'question' elements if you want to access the `ques` attribute.  `ctgy` will not have `ques`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ctgy.Attribute("ques").Value
ctgy.Attribute("rating").Value
```

There is no such attribute.

Also do a null check before doing things like

```
(string)ctgy.Element("opt2").Value,
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is on this line:

```
from ctgy in exm.Descendants("category")
```

The `exm` elements are at the same level of your categories. You need to replace `exm` with `data`.

Example:

```
from ctgy in data.Descendants("category")
```